# How can I improve my fibonacci sequence generator?

Tags: python, fibonacci

### What have I done?

---

I have made a **Fibonacci sequence generator**, see the code below:

```
prev_nums = [0, 1]
count = int(1) 

for i in range(20):
    count += 1
    ans = prev_nums[count-1] + prev_nums[count-2]
    print(ans)
    prev_nums.append(ans)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
...
```

Basically, I have a for loop. Every iteration, i will add `1` to the variable `count`, so that i can keep track of the index i should use to find the previous numbers to add together.

(*The next value in a fibonacci sequence is always equal to the two values before it added together*)

I then append the value in that specific iteration to the list `prev_nums` to keep track of all the values that i have already generated, so that i can generate the next one.

### How can I improve this code?

---

I have found some other examples online of a Fibonacci generator, such as:

```
def fibonacci():
    a=0
    b=1
    for i in range(6):
        print(b)
        a,b= b,a+b
```

and,

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Why are (or why not) are these solutions better/worse than my own and what can I learn from these to improve my own?

Comment: Depends on your use-case. The generator (the one with `yield`) is ideal in terms of memory, as it only ever needs to store two values in memory, and is also able to be very easily modified into an infinite sequence generator by changing to a `while True` loop. Generators can also be stopped and resumed at any time. You could modify your example to emulate the memory savings of the generator by only ever storing the previous two results, *but* your function would still only be able to run from start to finish, whereas the generator can be resumed at any time.

Comment: Your `count` variable is not necessary.  You can use `x[-2]` and `x[-1]` to get the last two elements of a list, although @ddejohn is correct to point out you don't need to store the whole list.  The question of whether this should be inline code, or a function that prints, or a function that returns the elements depends on your need.  There's no good/bad there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :D Very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours has some disadvantages:

1. It only prints the numbers. That reduces its usability to that particular side-effect. You cannot use the numbers for further processing.
2. It builds an ever-growing list that uses up memory even though you only ever need the last two elements.
3. You have hard-coded the number of fibonacci numbers you want to generate. You have to change the generation code if you need more of them.
4. It is not encapsulated in a function. That reduces its reusability.

Issues  1. and 3. also apply to the first alternative you proposed.

The parametrized generator function (second proposed alternative)

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

does not have any of those problems. If you want to print some numbers, you can easily do that (see how the purpose and count are left to the caller):

```
for f in fib(5):
    print(f)
```

or you can collect them in a `list` if you need to:

```
fib_nums = list(fib(5))
```

or apply a function to all of them:

```
for double_fib in map((2).__mul__, fib(5)):
    print(double_fib)
```

And if you need the numbers with their according index, there are built-in utils you can apply:

```
for i, f in enumerate(fib(5)):
    print(f"{i}: {f}")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining it clearly :D